# What would be a simple regular expression for password check during signup?

Tags: java, android, regex

What I want to do is just check when the user is signing up that whether the password entered is at least 6 characters and has no space in it. Thats pretty much it. What would be a regex that I could use in Java Pattern Matcher classes for this purpose?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a regex?

```
String str = "my pass";

if (str.length() < 6 || str.contains(" ")){

fail();
}
```

Comment: oh god!! thats so true...i just got out of validating email addresses entered during signup so i keep on thinking about complex regex etc....sorry i need to get back to thinking simple. My Bad!!

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use a regex?

```
public boolean isPasswordValid( String password )
{
    return ((password.length() >= 6) && (!password.contains(" "));
}
```

Comment: oh god!! thats so true...i just got out of validating email addresses entered during signup so i keep on thinking about complex regex etc....sorry i need to get back to thinking simple. My Bad!! Thanks.

Comment: Heh, RegEx's do seem to be the immediate solution to every problem, but as the adage goes "A man decided to use a regex to solve his problem, now he has two problems" (horribly paraphrased) ;)

Comment: @Keng: Not mine, it is a quote of Jamie Zawinski. [A page about the quote](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

Answer (score 3):

```
^[^ ]{6,}$
```

This will match the whole string ^...$ and ignore spaces [^ ] for 6 or more chars {6,}

Comment: Thanks @skyfoot..I was just not thinking about .length() function with which I can eliminate the overhead of regex just for such a simple criteria check actually.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern Matcher is a little overhead there, you can use the following:

```
String password = ...;
final int PASS_MIN_LEN = 6;
if (password.length >= PASS_MIN_LEN && password.indexOf(' ') < 0) {
 // proceed
} else {
 // error 
}
```

Comment: Yah it is. I will use the .length instead for such a simple criteria.